# How to save the depth image of ARCore

Tags: arcore

Please understand my poor English.

I want to get a depth image with ARcore and use the image in another language. To do so, I need to know how to save the image. **How can I save the depth image I got with ARcore?**

Depth image is an image object. I searched several times to understand the image, but I couldn't understand it.

Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer yourself to the following topic: [How to save 16bit depth Image to file in Arcore (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969159/how-to-save-16bit-depth-image-to-file-in-arcore-java/67027128#67027128)

An idea is to export the depth data as a textfile and then decode it to extract a sample containing the distance in millimeters.